# Dagger 2 compile time error on CI

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, dagger-2

I've been using Dagger 2 recently and just did some work with scopes in my android project, adding scopes for Activities. While everything runs, builds and tests fine on my own machine. I'm getting a compile error on Jenkins CI.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Adverts:compile***DebugJava'
.java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
```

This is strange because the build has worked fine up until now with Dagger 2 just with less code being generated. When I navigate to the generated sources some, but not all of the code is generated. It looks like it's crapping it out somewhere along the way. Both CI and my machine are using the same version of JDK.

Has anybody ran into issues with CI & Dagger 2 before?

Comment: This isn't Dagger 2's fault. *Something* is set up differently on your CI machine. When you compile on your local machine, are you doing it via Android Studio, or using the same script as the CI?

Comment: I'm using the same Gradle tasks to test locally and on CI. I ended up creating an osx slave with the same configuration on our jenkins setup and it worked. It's really strange, both the jdk and the android sdk are running the same versions on CI master as the slave. The only difference I can recognise is the OS.

Comment: In which case I'm stumped. I highly doubt dagger 2 us the culprit though, and the error you posted would appear to support that.

Answer (score 3):

For people in the future who encounter this error as well, it's most likely because of a class you deleted or a class that doesn't exist that is being referenced in your Module.

I had the exact same error while compiling when I had code like this:

```
@Module(includes = {
        AModuleThatDoesntExist.class
})
public class YourModule {
}
```

So what I'm saying is: if you encounter this error, check your Dagger modules and bootstrapper code, there's probably some invalid code there.

As to why it works on your machine and not on the CI server: I don't know. I would guess it's because of some cache issue where the .class file of your deleted .java file is still present on your local filesystem, so Dapper can find it, but it doesn't exist on your CI server. If you can still reproduce the issue, maybe you can try running "Rebuild" and see if the errors occurs locally too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinking it is issue of new Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks you saved my life

Answer (score 0):

Whatever happens Dagger 2's annotation processor shouldn't throw an exception so assuming that is coming from the Dagger 2 annotation processor it might be worth raising a bug if you can create a reproducible example, preferably a simple one.

As others have suggested do a clean build (remove the classes yourself to make sure that they are all gone) and check for differences between your machine and the CI one.